# How to find the smallest value in an infinite sequence whose liminf exist?

Tags: maxima-minima, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose we have a sequence $\{a_1,...,a_n,...\}$ with $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\liminf} a_n=A$. How to find the smallest value in this sequence?
My current intuition is that the smallest value might not always be attained in this sequence. And the only case in which the smallest value is obtained is when there exists relatively small values in the beginning of the sequence. In this case, for some given small $\epsilon>0$, I can always find $N$ such that the subsequence of small numbers denoted by ${a_{k_n}}$ with $k_n>N$ will fall within $[A-\epsilon,A+\epsilon]$. With relatively small values in the beginning of the sequence, I can find a number among $a_1,..,a_N$ that is smaller than $A-\epsilon$ which will be the smallest value in this sequence.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: What is the smallest value of $\{1/n\}?$

Comment: @miracle173 It's 0, attained when $n=\infty$. Maybe I have some conceptual misunderstanding, in this example, can we say 0 is attained in the sequence?

Comment: @T34driver No, it's not zero and there is no such term in that sequence as $\;n_\infty\;$ . And no, zero is not a part of that sequence and it is thus not attained. Zero is THE LIMIT of that sequence, whish is way another thing.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks! So my intuition in this question is correct, right?

Comment: @T34driver Not quit. The part "And the only case in which the smallest value is obtained is when there exists relatively small values in the beginning of the sequence." is either inaccurate or rather foggy (depending on what exactly you mean, which I can't say), since for example $\;\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n=0\;$, yet in this case the minimal value of the sequence exists and equals $\;-1\;$ ...which isn't even close to the lim inf...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks! I think your example agrees with my intuition. As the sequence you gave is -1, 1/2, -1/3, 1/4, ..., which in my foggy words is a sequence with relatively small values in the beginning (actually the first term is already the smallest).

Comment: @DonAntonio Perhaps a slightly more rigorous translation of "relatively small values in the beginning of the sequence" is that for some given $\epsilon$, after the $N$-th term, all small values in the sequence will be within $(\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\liminf} a_n-\epsilon, \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf} a_n+\epsilon)$ and among $a_1,...,a_N$ you can find some terms that are strictly smaller than $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\liminf}a_n -\epsilon$.